Can antihydrogen ions be mixed with liquid xenon stably?
Inspired partly by this article which claims positronium in liquid helium is substantially more stable than one might expect due to formation of "bubbles" and and a "repulsive force" I wanted to ask:
Question:
Can a mixture of anti-hydrogen $\bar{H}^{-}$ ions be mixed with a fluid or gas of noble gas atoms relatively stably?
Let's suppose we work with liquid xenon. If the temperatures are sufficiently low it seems extremely unlikely that the antihydrogen ions will come in contact with any of the xenon nuclei as both the antihydrogen ions and the 5 layer electron cloud of the xenon are both negatively charged and this force needs to be overcome in order for the anti hydrogen ions to delete themselves.
At sufficiently low temperatures it seems this will just NOT be possible (or will occur with an extremely negligible probability) that you effectively have semi-stable mixture of anti matter and matter. Is this an accurate conclusion?
See the image below:


For some value of 'stable', the environment will impact stability. Just like in positron annihilation spectroscopy.
